# PHP Facebook SDK 4 doesnt prompt users for permissions

Tags: php, facebook

When users are trying to log in to my app the dialog box, asking for permission is not apearing.
My code is:

```
           $facebook = new Facebook(array(
           'appId' => 'myappid',
           'secret' => 'mysecret'
            ));

        if($facebook->getUser() == 0){
        $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
       'scope' => 'email'
        ));

       else{
           $api = $facebook->api('me');
           echo "Hi " . $api[name];
           $user_profile = $facebook->api('me', array('fields' => 'email'));
           .....
       }
```

I have also tried to use this:

```
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
 'req_perms' => 'publish_stream, read_friendlists'
  ));
```

But again users are not asked for permissions to allow it. 
I guess that this is probably due to some settings configuration...

Comment: You are aware that you have to redirect the user to the `$loginUrl` in their browser, right …?

Comment: Right, I am aware that I have to redirect them. After user provides credentials logic in else statement is being executed and dialog box for permission is not appears.

Comment: In your headline you are talking about the SDK v4, but your code looks like it is using v3 – so which is it?

Comment: Sorry it is my mistake. The version which I use is v3.

Comment: Then I would suggest that you use v4 because it is newer and maintained.